# Implications of "Loggers should be private static"

Tags: sonarqube

I've recently read http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1312 (Loggers should be "private static [final|const]" and should share a naming convention) and I wonder whether this rule would bring implications for my application.

We are developing web applications that hold Spring Beans in a per-user session, which are using commons-logging w/ log4j for logging.
When we would define our loggers "static" there would be no chance to reconfigure the loglevels with a custom LogFactory per session, so all users would share the same loglevel.

Since there's discussion about this rule I'd like to ask if this use case is a new one for you or if there's a better way for logger separation in web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Loggers are not static fields then they are instance fields (obviously :)). That implicates that they are created with each new instance, serialized together with the instance (which is not desirable), etc.

I am not aware of any catastrophic implications if they are not static (provided that you take care of the potential downsides, of course).

However, I would rather take a different approach to solve your requirement. I would still use the static Logger internally, but I would not operate directly with the Logger, but rather with some proxy which would dynamically calculate what is logged for a user. For example:

```
private static final Logger logger = MyCustomLoggerFactory.createLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

Then I would intercept all the calls to the logger and decide what is logged based on the user (user info is bound to the thread in some way I assume, so you could easily get it in the interceptor/proxy).

Besides being a cleaner solution, this gives you more flexibility. For example, you could change the log level for a user after their session has been initialized (if some conditions change, say an administrator turns on debug logging for all the currently logged-in users), or you could do something additionally with the message (duplicate it to a separate file for some users, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my loggers are always defined as transient, so serialisation is not an issue. Do I understand your example corectly, the Factory does create a logger proxy instead a framework-specific implementation? I believed this was the purpose of commons-logging to provide an abstraction from different implementations.

Comment: True. But your requirements are not covered by commons-logging, that's why I would add another abstraction on top of it. This is just adhering to OOP principles, like encapsulation and proven design patterns.